# Office 365 migration from G Suite, Users receiving bounce backs?

Tags: migration, microsoft-office-365, g-suite, office365

We have recently moved to a company from G Suite to Office 365. The migration seemed to go ok. However, all users are receiving tons of bounce back internally and externally. We first believed it was to do with the autocomplete files. so we went through those with N2k edit and fixed any issues in there. We are still having issues with this. Any ideas?

Comment: Presumably your problem is related to moving their email from GMail to Exchange Online. While GMail is included in all G Suite subscriptions, Exchange Online isn't included in all Office 365 subscriptions. When you say you moved them to Office 365 it isn't and shouldn't be assumed that you mean Exchange Online. What's the nature of these bounces? Are these bounces received by your client when your client  sends internal and external email or are these bounces that external senders receive when sending email to your client?

Comment: What's the error message... SPF reconfigured properly?

Comment: You really need to post the contents of the NDR message your users are receiving. Based on your description it almost sounds like your users were using Outlook already with Gmail then you migrated them to Office 365 and tried to continue to use the existing Outlook profiles in some way. This would be a big problem being Gmail has no relationship to Exchange whatsoever - Outlook profiles should be completely rebuilt from scratch. Without an NDR it’s impossible to tell you what might be wrong - it isn’t just something - it tells everything about what’s wrong.

Comment: Hi Guys,  Thanks for getting back to me. I have done some more digging. the bounce backs are sent from office 365 as office 365 does not send them out. The issue seems to be old/corrupt Autocomplete emails. Microsoft called these Bad Entries and said the only way to fix is to delete them as you go or clear the whole autocomplete. here is some of the NDR: Your email program is using outdated address information for IMCEAEX-K@GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM.
sgrowcott Office 365 IMCEAEX-K
Action Required Recipient
Outdated To address. we are going about trying to remove these ba dentries one by one